# Python hangman script will not work if there are spaces

Tags: python-3.x

current code -

```
string = input("Enter word")
guessed= False
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
guesses=[]


while guessed== False:
    char = input("Enter one letter :").lower()
    if len(char) == 1:
        if char not in alphabet:
            print("Error you have not entered a letter")
        elif char in guesses:
            print("Letter has been guessed before")
        elif char not in string:
            print("Sorry this letter is not part of the word")
            guesses.append(char)
        elif char in string:
            print("Well done")
            guesses.append(char)
        else:
            print("Error")
    else:
        print("Only 1 character should be entered")

    status= ''
    if guessed == False:
        for letter in string:
            if letter in guesses:
                status+=letter
                if status==string:
                    print("Congratulations you have won")
                    guessed=True
            else:
                status+='_'
        print(status)
```

If the word is "hello world" and the user guessed the words correctly the output below is displayed:

```
Well done
hello_world
Enter one letter :
```

The user is asked again to enter another letter even though the word is found. Im not sure on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an extra condition for spaces like this

```
for letter in string:
    if letter in guesses:
        status+=letter
        if status==string:
            print("Congratulations you have won")
            guessed=True
    elif letter == ' ':
        status += ' '
    else:
        status+='_'
```

This way the user sees that there are actually two words but does not have to enter a space explicitly.

**Output**

```
Enter one letter :h
Well done
h____ _____
Enter one letter :e
Well done
he___ _____
...
Enter one letter :d
Well done
Congratulations you have won
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

`hello world` contains a space, and yet space is not allowed as a guessed letter, so even if the user guesses all the right letters, the `status` will at best become `hello_world`, which is not equal to `hello world`, leaving the game unfinished.